# cudaErrorInvalidDevice when using nvc++ -stdpar

Tags: c++, std, thrust

I'm trying to run the following basic C++ program using stdpar and the `nvc++` compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 10, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5, 1 };
    std::cout << "Elements before sorting" << std::endl;
    std::sort(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine using `-stdpar -gpu=cc86`, but the line `std::sort(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end());` throws the following error when running using `./a.out`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  radix_sort: failed on 1st step: cudaErrorInvalidDevice: invalid device ordinal
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Because the HPC SDK for CUDA is only available on Linux, I'm currently running all of the above in a Windows subsystem. I've checked and the versions of CUDA and HPC SDK match and point to the right folders. Also, I've set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` just to make sure CUDA was accessing the correct GPU but unfortunately the error persists. Because the error mentions `thrust::system::system_error`, could this be a bug or problem with thrust? The program runs fine if you replace `std::execution::par` by `std::execution::seq` so that would point in the direction of thrust. Is there anything else that I can try? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test running something compiled with nvcc in the same environment? E.g. some [CUDA samples](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction)? Just to differentiate between there being some problem with nvc++ specifically or this being a general problem of your setup.

Comment: I used the 21.9 HPC SDK container from https://ngc.nvidia.com  on a system with  a V100 GPU.  I compiled your code using `nvc++ -stdpar -gpu=cc70 test.cu -o test`.  And there are no errors when I run it.  My guess would be you have a broken or mismatched environment of some sort.  There is not enough info here to diagnose.

Comment: There is a driver problem, running `nvidia-smi` says it can't connect to the driver.

Comment: so you have a broken environment